# How to include posts from one category, into a separate category of posts?

Tags: loop

How would I insert one category of *featured* posts into another category of posts?

So, the second, fifth and eleventh are posts from a completely different category.

Hope the below illustration makes sense.

[image: Example]

Comment: There are numerous questions/answers here concerning inserting various extra data into query results. Have you read any of them? Certainly you can find enough information to get started on your own code?

Comment: Extra data, yes, nothing complete though for posts. Thus, my question.